# I am trying to filter out data but not able to display them properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI to display a dummy data from a json file onto the table.

I have an input field which **onChange** event would call the function to filter out data based on input and show on the table. The filter of the data works and is displayed on the table as the last row but the old data is also shown as well. I have tried different ways but still could not figure out what is the issue.

```
const [sdata, setsData] = useState(Data); // data from file
const [searched, setSearched] = useState(""); // maintain state of the search field
const [filteredResults, setFilterdResults] = useState([]) // maintain state of filtered data


  // function to filter data...
  const requestSearch = (value) => {
let filteredData = sdata.filter((val) => {
  if (searched === '') {
    return val
  } else {
    return val.student_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
  }
})
setFilterdResults(filteredData)
console.log("Filtered Data", filteredData)
}

 // search input filed **only one for now**
<div className="search">
    <Box
      sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", paddingRight: "10px" }}
    >
      <SearchIcon sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
      <TextField
        id="student"
        label="Student"
        variant="standard"
        value={searched}
        onChange={(evt) => {
          setSearched(evt.target.value)
          requestSearch(evt.target.value);
          // console.log(evt.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <SearchIcon sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
      <TextField id="zone" label="Zone" variant="standard" />

    </Box>
  </div>

// displaying data based on condition (if there is a searched input or not)
 <TableContainer>
    <Table aria-label="studentInfo">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          {columns.map((col) => (
            <TableCell
              sx={{
                backgroundColor: "#662d91",
                color: "white",
                fontSize: matches ? "12" : "18px",
                fontWeight: "bold",
              }}
              key={col.id}
              align={col.align}
              style={{
                minWidth: matches ? col.minWidth : col.mobWidth,
                paddingLeft: "5px",
              }}
            >
              {col.label}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {searched.length = 1 ? (
          <>
            {
              filteredResults.map((std) => (
                <StyledTableRow
                  // style={{ backgroundColor: getZoneColor(std.zone) }}
                  key={std.tg}
                >
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.tg}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.student_name}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.admin_no}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.action}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell
                    style={{
                      color:
                        // "black",
                        getZoneColor(std.zone),
                    }}
                  >
                    {std.zone}
                  </StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableRow>
              ))
            }
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            {
              sdata.map((std) => (
                <StyledTableRow
                  // style={{ backgroundColor: getZoneColor(std.zone) }}
                  key={std.tg}
                >
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.tg}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.student_name}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.admin_no}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell>{std.action}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell
                    style={{
                      color:
                        // "black",
                        getZoneColor(std.zone),
                    }}
                  >
                    {std.zone}
                  </StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableRow>
              ))
            }
          </>
        )}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
```

The weird thing is if I force reload the tab and do the search it runs flawlessly but the next time I search it causes the issue

- After force reload first search
  [image: Initial]
- The next search [image: after initial search]

Answer (score 0):

try code below

```
const filterData = (inputValue) => {
const filteredData = sdata.filter(i => i.student_name?.includes(inputValue))
setsetSearched(inputValue);
setFilterdResults(filteredData)
}
```

call the function on onChange property of your input

```
<input onChange={(e)=> filterData(e.target.value)} />
```

and change your condition to this

```
searched.length > 0
```

Comment: Tried this but still results in the same thing.